# Stack dump without killing process in windows

Tags: windows, stack-trace, dump

I'm looking for a method to get a stack dump without killing the running process in win32 platform, which means that the thread dumping its stack should return to the original context after stack dumping. (like usual function call) Is it possible in windows?

Comment: Are you talking about writing a code to do the task? If so, what language (or at least language family).

Comment: Ah, I forgot to specify my language. I use C/C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360%28VS.85%29.aspx) function from the [`DbgHelp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) library.

Note, however, that it is recommended to create the dump from a different process. Attempts to create it from the same process might have undesirable side effects. Read the documentation for this function carefully.